# Summernote with Meteor content duplication

Tags: meteor, summernote

I'm having an issue with Summernote in Meteor project. After I submit form the content is duplicated.

Here's my markup:

```
{{#with entity}}
<div class="content">{{{content}}}</div>
<button>Edit</button>
{{/with}}
```

Edit button click handler:

```
$('.content').summernote();
```

Form submission handler:

```
var $editor = $('.content'), content = $editor.code();
$editor.destroy();
Entity.update(this._id, { $set: { content: content } });
```

After `$editor.destroy()` is called, the `.content` element is back to its original non-editable state with an updated content. But on next Tracker flush cycle Blaze appends new `entity.content` to `<div class="content">` and I see content duplication.

A simple reproduction scenario:

1. Let's say original `entity.content` is `Hello, world!`.
2. Click on Edit and change to `Bye bye, world!` then submit the form.
3. We have `entity.content` equals `Bye bye, world!` but the markups looks like this:

   ```
   <div class="content"><p>Bye bye, world!</p><p>Bye bye, world!</p></div>
   ```

I have an idea how to solve that but I don't like it. I can compare new content and original one upon form submission. In case the content hasn't changed there will not be duplication so the code above works. But if content differs do this: `$editor.destroy().html('')`. On next Tracker flush Blaze will insert an updated content.

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Same, so i don't use `$editor.destroy`  but

```
$('.note-editor').remove();
$editor.show();
```